# How to set a value in a form in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

To set a value in a form programmatically with Symfony2, after a form has been created, I've found that the following way works:

```
$form_data = $form->getData();
$form_data['name'] = 'new value';
$form->setData($form_data);
```

This is awkward, isn't there a simpler way like `$form->set('name', 'new value');` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913086/how-to-set-default-value-for-form-field-in-symfony2?rq=1

Comment: @DainisAbols nope, I saw that question. I don't want a default value, I want to change after the form has been set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$form->get('name')->setData('new value');
```