# Symfony validation slow

Tags: php, performance, validation, symfony

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong in symfony to validate a request.

I have a controller which receives a User via a POST request

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $params = $request->request->all();
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($params['username']);
    $user->setEmail($params['email']);
    $user->setPassword($params['password']);

    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user);

    if(count($errors) > 0)
    {
        return $this->respond(['errors' => $errors], 422);
    }
    else 
    {
        $user = $this->get('userrepository')->create($user);
        return $this->respond($user, 201);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I first create the User, then pass it to the validator service and return the errors if any, otherwise I ask my repository to create the user in the database.

The validation I use is the following (YAML):

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: email
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
        email:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Email:
                message: The email {{ value }} is not a valid email.
        password:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

Now the validation works, but it takes Symfony around 3000ms to respond in a `dev env` with an empty database.

What could be the cause of this `absurdly` long response time ?

Other GET/POST request without validation only take 250-300 ms to complete.

PS: I've tried putting the validation rules into the Entity as Annotations, but there is no difference in response time.

Comment: Try to test without the unique entity constraint.

Comment: I tried that and it does not affect the response time much (maybe 50 ms). So that doesn't seem to be the cause

Comment: Strange. Can you profile your request with blackfire.io?

Comment: Not sure if I will be able to, any other way i can profile it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For future reference:

The issue for me was using the `/web/app_dev.php/...` to access symfony instead of using the build in server in development.

`$ php app/console server:run`