# How to set default value on Symfony3 EntityType?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to set a default value on EntityType select like this:

```
$builder
            ->add('town', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => "TOWN",
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Town',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'),
                'placeholder' => 'CHOOSE_AN_OPTION',
                'required' => false,
                'data' => $this->em->getReference('AppBundle:Town', $options['attr']['town'])
            ));
```

I was trying to do it using data option. It works fot a ChoiceType, but not for EntityType. I tried to pass to the data option the town entity **ID**, **Name** and the **entire object**.

I create the form object from the controller:

```
$finder = $this->createForm(UserFinderType::class, null,
        array('attr' => array('role' => $this->getUser()->getRole(),
            'town'     => empty($params['town']) ? null : $townService->findOneById($params['town'])->getId() )));
```

When I pass Town ID or Name nothing happens, placeholder is shown. If I remove placeholder, blank option is selected.

When I pass entire Town object, this error is returned: `Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\Town could not be converted to string`

And, if I implement a __toString method, I get the same result that I get on ID or Name try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45468030/4224384

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `__toString` function in `Town` class:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Town

.................

public function __toString(){
    return $this->name; // If you have `name` field or u can return `id`
}
```