# How can i set default value to datetime filter form Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

So i need to set default value to documentDate filter but there is no option like data => 'date'

```
->add(
            'documentDate',
            'datetime',
            [
                'title' => $this->translate('Date of invoice'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'date_format' => 'L',
                'name' => 'date_range',
                'class' => 'datatable_datepicker print-date',
                'export_options' => [
                    'visible' => true,
                    'render' => function ($line) {
                        if ($line['documentDate'] instanceof \DateTimeInterface) {
                            $line['documentDate'] = (new DateFormatter())->format($line['documentDate']);
                        }

                        return $line;
                    },
                ],
            ]
        )
```

Comment: In your call to create the form, set the data to apply the value you desire. `$formFactory->create(MyForm::class, ['documentDate' => new DateTime()])`, otherwise if you are using a model, set the value in the model prior to passing it to the Form. Alternatively you can use [`POST_SET_DATA` event](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/form/events.html) on the desired form field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I specify default values in a Symfony form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466928/how-do-i-specify-default-values-in-a-symfony-form)