# Best practice for changing default parameter of form object after getForm() symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony

I updated and summurized the question.

What I want to do is changing the default value of form object after getForm()

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $task = new Task();   
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', TextType::class,array('data' => 'default text data') // Set the default data for loaded first time. 
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //I want change the default value of task, I tried a few methods.
         $d = $form->getData();
         $form->get('task')->setData('replace text data'); // not work
         $d->setData('second data'); // notwork

    }
```

Is it possible or how??

Comment: Just add `$task->setTask('Your Default Text');` prior to your `createFormBuilder` row. (Or set that value in the Task class itself, either in the constructor or as a default for the `$task` class-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default value for form field in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913086/how-to-set-default-value-for-form-field-in-symfony2)

Comment: I think I could se the default task but I would like to change this after submitted

Comment: @yceruto , I guess myquesion is a bit different so , I updated the question itself

Comment: You means the data associated to the task field in the form after submitted?

Comment: You cannot change the data of a submitted form, so you might need re-create the form with the new default value.

Comment: I see. I solved my problem by making new entity object.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this one.

 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $even) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (isset($data['task'])) {

            $data['task'] = "Default Task1";              
            $event->setData($data); 
        }
    });
```